# Testing disabled property on a Ionic component in Ionic VueJs

Tags: unit-testing, ionic-framework, vuejs3, vue-test-utils, vitest

I have a Ionic 7 application made with VueJs 3.
I'm writing tests using [vue-test-utils](https://v1.test-utils.vuejs.org/) and [Vitest](https://vitest.dev/)

I have this template:

```
<!-- language: html -->
     <ion-segment>
        <ion-segment-button ref="map-segment" class="map" value="/tabs/tab3" :disabled="isDisabled">
            <ion-label>Map</ion-label>
        </ion-segment-button>
    </ion-segment>
```

with `isDisabled` set to false by default.

And this test:

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->    
    import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
    import TabsPage from '@/views/TabsPage.vue'
    import { describe, expect, test } from 'vitest'
    import { createTestingPinia } from '@pinia/testing'
    import { IonicVue, IonSegmentButton } from '@ionic/vue';

    describe('TabsPage.vue', () => {

      test('renders TabsPage', () => {
        const wrapper = mount(TabsPage, {
          global: {
            plugins: [createTestingPinia(), IonicVue]
          },
        })  
    
        const segments = wrapper.findAllComponents(IonSegmentButton)
        expect(segments).toHaveLength(1) // assert is ok

        const mapTab = wrapper.findComponent({ ref: 'map-segment' })

        console.log(mapTab)    
      })
    })
```

I want to test if my `ion-segment` component is disabled.
The DOM looks like this:
[image]

So I tried to test the presence of the `segment-button-disabled` class but the test only see the `map` class I've added and not the Ionic ones.

I also wanted to access the shadow-root to directly test the `disabled` attribute on the button but did not find anything in the documentation to do that.

Does someone know how to test Ionic components properties in VueJs ? Or have a great documentation/tutorial to share with me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found how to do it !

We can access Ionic component property with the `props()` method: `myComponent.props().yourProperty`

Example:

```
const mapTab = wrapper.findComponent({ ref: 'map-segment' })
expect(mapTab.props().disabled).toBeTruthy()
```